# Jupyter Docker on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-container-os

I would like to run a Jupyter notebook from a docker image on GCP. Specifically I would like to run the one from `kaggle/python`. On my local machine I can get this working with `docker pull kaggle/python` and then the following docker cli command:

`docker run -v $PWD:/tmp/working -w=/tmp/working -p 8888:8888 --rm -it kaggle/python jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip="0.0.0.0" --notebook-dir=/tmp/working/src`

**I do not want to use a `gcloud` cli command.** How do I map this command to the GUI in GCP? I wan't to run this on Google Containerized OS:

[image]

Comment: The GCP console works through API calls, as does the `gcloud` commands. Other than using `gcloud` to interact with the Compute Engine API, are through various programming language's [client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries), & the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert). See [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/apis) for more details about the compute engine API. You can also try using GKE to deploy containers.

Is this what you're looking for? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use docker containers to your custom notebook environment on GCP's AI Platform Notebooks.  That might serve your means

They offer a base container that you can modify to fit your needs and then use as your active notebook environment

You can find more info about them here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-containers